# Network card suddently doesn't answer anymore, but answers after pinging

Tags: linux, networking, hardware, drivers

We have a problem with the network card on a Dell Power Edge R410 with Debian 6 (squeeze). It seems that the network card went into "sleep" mode after some time. If we are connected via ssh to the server, the connection drops after a certain period of inactivity. If we then ping the server, it doesn't answer to the first packets, but after 5-10 seconds it's answering again.

Here are the configuration details:

OS:

```
2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Wed May 18 23:13:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

NIC Driver:

```
Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet bnx2 v2.6.29-11:26
driver: bnx2
version: 2.0.2
firmware-version: 5.0.11 NCSI 2.0.5
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
```

UPDATE: I'm not sure, but maybe not only the network card but the whole server went to sleep mode. I can't see anything in /var/log/messages when it happends, if someone knows haw I can increase the loglevel to see more let me know.

Comment: Do all your computers in your network have unique IP numbers?

Comment: Yes, we can be sure that we use unique IPs. We had OpenSuse installed before with the same IP adresses where we didn't have that problem.

Comment: Can you post a packet dump from affected machine and from a remote machine?

Comment: @Mircea: How exactly would you perform such a dump (especially on a busy server), and what could you read from it?

Comment: @Chris Lercher: you can use one of `tcpdump`, `dumpcap` or `tshark`

Comment: What makes you think that the network card goes into sleep mode? Anything anywhere in some logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue. After upgrading the bnx2 network driver to version 2.0.23b the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on either Linux, but perhaps its related to power settings?

Most servers/OSs have settings to control power consumption and they can turn off or put to sleep some hardware components if they're idle for some time. Perhaps squeeze is configured by default to allow the NIC to go to sleep, or maybe this setting is configured in the BIOS of the server and the OS just doesn't override it.

Check the settings in the BIOS and OS. In the BIOS it should be under POWER.

Comment: I disabled all acpi stuff, but the problem is still there. I put a cron job which pings every 20 minutes 5 times the server. Sometimes it is not answering directly. I startet tshark on the server capturing imcp packages, let's see if the server receives the pings ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem was caused by the one described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150718022644/http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.hardware.dell.poweredge/38721)

Here's a solution like answer:

> I haven't upgraded any of our boxes from 5.4 yet, but I have to say
>   I've had two big problems with the stock bnx2 NIC drivers from 5.4
>   (for both R610s and R710s).  The first problem was that the NICs would
>   just die randomly when under heavy load, which required a network
>   restart.  This in particular can be resolved by adding options 
>   `bnx2 disable_msi=1` to `/etc/modprobe.conf`.  After that, I was finding that a
>   box which was in production would occasionally start intermittently
>   losing packets/connectivity, which also required a network restart.  **I
>   couldn't resolve this without getting the latest NIC drivers from the
>   Dell website**.
>
> Now I don't have any problems, but I've stopped my kernel from
>   automatically updating until I set the NIC driver up using DKMS.
>
> It's not easy to test that the problem could be fixed in RHEL/CentOS
>   5.5, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the problem is on the server or in your network.

Are you connecting to this server from the same IP subnet where it resides or from another one?

What do you see if you start a network sniffer (such as WireShark) on the server after a connection drops and then try to ping it from another computer?

Comment: We worked arround the problem by installing Open Suse. There the problem does not appear. Today we again installed Debian squeeze on a Dell Power Edge R410, we still se that problem. The problem seems to be Debian specific ...